# Caching input filter results

Tags: 8, caching, input-formats

I'm creating an input filter that is quite expensive, as it makes a call to a remote service as part of the processing of the output.

In Drupal 7, I'm pretty sure that the filtered output of an input filter was cached by default, but I'm finding in D8 that it is not being cached, and the content is being passed through the filter on every page load.

I've tried setting the generated text with FilterProcessResult::setProcessedText(), however it's still being loaded.

Code:

```
class FilterRemoteUrlTitle extends FilterBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function process($text, $langcode) {
    $result = new FilterProcessResult($text);

    // Do some stuff to $text (not shown)

    // Set the processed text.
    $result->setProcessedText($text);

    return $result;
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: FilterProcessResult should be cached according to the cache metadata it contains upstream in the entity the field is placed in. However, there can be cache metadata bubbling up from other elements preventing it is getting cached.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I guess it's changed somewhat since D7. What you say makes sense though. I guess I have to figure out why my entity isn't caching. Thanks.